# CHORD_TYPE for Chord in music21

Tags: python, music21

The property `Chord.commonName` returns the most common name associated with a chord. The returned string is from the table [chord.tables.tnIndexToChordInfo](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/blob/f457a2ba52ea3f978d805cd52fa101dfb0dd8577/music21/chord/tables.py#L981) and has e.g. the form `dominant seventh chord`

On the other side there is the table [harmony.CHORD_TYPES](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/blob/f457a2ba52ea3f978d805cd52fa101dfb0dd8577/music21/harmony.py#L60) where the chord is named `dominant-seventh`.

`CHORD_TYPES` is used by class `Harmony`. `tnIndexToChordInfo` is used by class `Chord`.

Is there a way in `music21` to get the representation in `CHORD_TYPES` having the `tnIndexToChordInfo`?

Use case: I use Chords generated from `RomanNumeral` in a `Scale` and want to display the shortname in the `lyric`. The `commonName` is too long.

```py
k = scale.MelodicMinorScale('c')
rn = roman.RomanNumeral('V7', k, caseMatters=False)
c = chord.Chord(rn)
c.lyric = rn.figure + "\n" + rn.commonName
```